# Apache very slow at serving images

Tags: apache-2.4, magento

I have a very strange issue with Apache.
It is very slow when serving images, but only for images in a particular folder.

The site is using Magento, but I don't think this is the issue.

Has you can see in the following image, the first image of 179kb in the directory www.site.com/img/ is downloaded in  115ms

The others images in www.site.com/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/ of 100-200kb, are downloaded in 1-1.5 seconds.

[image: See the image here]

This makes the whole site very slow.

Where can be the issue?

Comment: Is that other path on a different file system?

Comment: Is the server able to lookup DNS without issue? What about the dev tools error console? Any missing images? js errors? What about external scripts to analytics that could be timing out. I would eliminate these before you look at file system issues.

Comment: File system is EXT4, and it's the same one for both directory.
The directory has "only" 749 files.

The method i used are the web site webpagetest.org and the browser dev tools.

I have looked at the parameter "Content Download" of the images.
There aren't missing images or js errors, but the "Content Download" i believe isn't influenced by them.

Comment: who has upvoted this? There is no information whatsoever. Nor the configuration of the virtualhost, or the mpm of apache or the limits configured, not a single glance at mod_status,  not a mention if those are really static and nor served by an application under a language intepreter, etc. But yes, there is a quick dismissal or any alternatives causing this. To me this sounds as your php framework is serving those files.